# Find out specific Rancher RKE K8s image versions

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am wondering where I can find which containers versions will be deployed when I install a K8s Cluster with the following version combinations:

```
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/releases/tag/v2.6.4
https://github.com/rancher/rke/releases/tag/v1.3.8
v1.22.7-rancher1-1
```

In the version file all image versions that are needed for all the k8s versions supported by the Rancher version are listed: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/releases/download/v2.6.4/rancher-images-sources.txt However, I would like to know where to find the mapping from K8s version to the component versions.

(Especially to find out which flannel version is deployed with K8s v1.22.7-rancher1-1, to see if is >= 0.15.1 to check for Debian bullseye compatability.)

Thank's a lot!

Comment: I just found out how to list the images that are coming with the default version of the rke binary:

`rke config --system-images --version v1.22.7-rancher1-1`